# Variable with memory allocated within another function

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, malloc

In regards to allocating memory to a variable, if I create a variable and send it to another function that allocated memory within that function and returns the result to the variable I created, will the original variable have the correct allocated memory?

Here's an example, question in regards to the comments:

```
char** fnTest(char* string) {

    char** rArray = malloc( 2 * sizeof(char*));

    // Same example here. string was technically already malloc'd from main. Is the string here also malloc'd as well?
    rArray[0] = string;

    return rArray;

}

int main() {

    char* inputString = malloc(5);
    strcpy(inputString, "test");

    // Question is in regards to pArray. Will this variable get malloc'd correctly?
    char** pArray;
    pArray = fnTest(inputString);



    // Everythign will be free'd from another function, but to keep it simple I'm not including it here.

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `inputString = "test";` overwrites your pointer to the block you allocated with `char* inputString = malloc(5);` causing a memory leak and setting your pointer `inputString` to point to the *string literal* `"test"`.

Comment: Do you have access to valgrind? If you're making memory mistakes it can usually find them for you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write strcpy(inputString, "test"), fixed it. In this case everything is fine now correct?

Comment: Ok-- got it, but ... Where is `string` in `pArray = fnTest(string);` declared?

Comment: Ah really sorry, fixed that to inputString. I just whipped this up quickly based on the actual project I'm working on. Sorry for the mistakes. Now it should be as I originally meant.

Comment: I think I know what your asking, if you declare `char *string;` in `main()` and want to pass it to say `void fntest()` for allocating, then you must pass the *address of* the pointer so `fntest()` receives the address of the actual pointer instead of a copy-of the pointer, e.g. `void fntest (char **string)` and call it as `fntest(&string)` from `main()`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see, that makes sense. In the same aspect, I am also wondering about the return of the function `fnTest` itself. If I declare `char** pArray` in `main()`, setting it to `pArray = fnTest(inputString)`, since I allocated `char** rArray` inside fnTest, will pArray be correctly allocated as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to allocate within a function without assigning the return of the allocation back in the calling function, then you can't simply pass a pointer to the function to allocate. Why? C is pass-by-value and when a variable is passed as a parameter, the function receives a *copy of the variable* with its own and very different address than the original variable in the caller. Any changes made to the variable in the function will never be seen back in the caller.

To handle this scenario, you can pass the address of the variable (e.g. a pointer) and update the value at the original address in memory. When you are talking about a variable that is already a pointer, the same applies, you must pass the address of the pointer as a parameter, so the function receives a pointer containing the original pointer address. You can then allocate/reallocate using the original pointer address and have the changes visible back in the caller. A short example may help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHAR 64

void fntest (char **s)
{
    void *tmp = realloc (*s, NCHAR);   /* allocate - using realloc */

    if (!tmp)                          /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("realloc-*s");

    *s = tmp;   /* assign new block of memory (or NULL) to original address */
}

int main (void) {

    char *string = NULL;    /* must be initialized NULL */

    fntest (&string);       /* call fntest to allocate string */

    if (string) {           /* validate allocation succeeded */
        strcpy (string, "some stuff");      /* copy some stuff */
        printf ("string: %s\n", string);    /* output it */
        free (string);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/allocinfn
string: some stuff
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/allocinfn
==7962== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7962== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7962== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7962== Command: ./bin/allocinfn2
==7962==
string: some stuff
==7962==
==7962== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7962==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7962==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 64 bytes allocated
==7962==
==7962== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7962==
==7962== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7962== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**A Preferred Alternative - Utilize the Function Return**

While there is nothing wrong with passing the address of the pointer (and in fact in list allocations, etc.. it is required), when simply allocating in a separate function, you can declare the variable within the function, allocate the required space, **validate** the allocation succeeded, and then return a pointer to the new block of memory and assign it back in `main()`. This simplifies things slightly. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCHAR 64

char *fntest (size_t size)
{
    void *memptr = malloc (size);     /* simply allocate size bytes */

    if (!memptr)                      /* validate! */
        perror ("malloc-memptr");

    return memptr;                    /* return pointer to new block (or NULL) */
}

int main (void) {

    char *string = fntest (NCHAR);

    if (string) {           /* validate allocation succeeded */
        strcpy (string, "some stuff");      /* copy some stuff */
        printf ("string: %s\n", string);    /* output it */
        free (string);      /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }
}
```

(output and memory check are the same)

Look both over and let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: I have fixed everything and have it working, but one last thing. The function I had in the beginning `char** fnTest(char** string)` returns the array of pointers `char** rArray` which gets allocated memory in the function. Is `pArray` in  `int main()` which gets set equal to the return of `fnTest()` correctly allocated the memory that gets malloc'd within `fnTest()`? In the example case it was the `char** rArray = (2 * sizeof(char*));`

Comment: From what I understand it would be fine since it is utilizing the return function like you said in the last part, I'm just making sure I understand correctly.

Comment: `char** rArray = (2 * sizeof(char*));` allocates storage for two-pointers only. Returning `rArrays` and assigning to a `char**` pointer in `main()` would correctly allocate, return and assign that block for two-pointers.

Answer (score 1):

In `fnTest`, the pointer `string` is copied to `rArray[0]` and the pointer `rArray` is returned to `main()` where it is *copied* to `pArray`.

In the end you have:

```
                -------
inputString -> |t|e|s|t|
pArray[0]   ->  -------

pArray[1] -> undefined
```

where `inputString` and `pArray[0]` point to the same location.

If your were to free `inputString`, `pArray[0]` would no longer be safe to use, while if you free'ed `pArray` input string would remain valid. Equally you could free `pArray[0]` and `inputString` would beinvalid, as both actions would free the same block containing "test".  Freeing both would also be invalid.